# With bind/on change how to show a Row

Tags: javascript, binding, coldfusion, onchange

I have a form using coldfusion that currently is using binding to generate a value. After a user selects from a pull down a selection is automatically generates a value 'Y' or 'N' generated from a table. What I need to do is use that value, in this case if value is 'Y' to display more questions to be answered. Here is what the current coding looks like.

```
<td>Select Category:
  <cfselect name="catdesc"
  title="Select category to generate related services"
  bind="cfc:servicetype2.cat_description()"
  bindonload="true"/><br />
</td>
</tr>                                               
<tr id="serv_ty2" style="display: inline;">
  <td></td>
  <td>Select Service:
  <cfselect name="service_type"
  bind="cfc:servicetype2.getServiceType2({catdesc})"
  bindonload="false"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id="lr_verify" style="display: inline;">
  <td></td>
  <td>Labor Relations Required:
  <cfinput name="lr_needed" <!---
    onchange="document.getElementById('lr_question').style.display = (this.selectedIndex == Y) ? 'inline' : 'none'"--->
    bind="cfc:servicetype2.getLR({service_type})"
    onchange="editLR()"
    bindonload="false"/></td>
</tr>
```

Here is the additional questions I want to show if Y is generated

```
<TR id="lr_question" name="lr_question" style="display: none;">
  <td align="left" nowrap>nbsp;<b>Additional Question:</b><br>(Hold Ctrl to select multiple)</td>
  <td align="left">Question:<br><br>
  <select id="lr_quest" name="lr_quest" multiple="multiple" required="NO" size="5">
    <option name="abc" id="abc">
    Choice 1</option>
    <option name="abc2" id="abc2">
    Choice 2</option>
  </select>
```

From my research I tried two solutions but neither work I am assuming I have the incorrect syntax or my thinking is correct.

Here is what the attempt java function was:

```
function editLR()
{
  // if 'Y' then additional questions for service type should show
  var lrshow = document.getElementById("lr_needed");
  if( lrshow == 'Y' ) {
    lr_question.style.display = "inline";           
  }
  else if ( lrshow == 'N' ) {
    lr_question.style.display = "none"; 
  }
  else if ( lrshow == '' ) {
    lr_question.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any suggestion I apologize if I did not explain myself correctly. Thanks in advance for any assistances I am still new to javascript and coldfusion so learning all the elements that are available still.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you have this:

```
var lrshow = document.getElementById("lr_needed");
```

Add this line after it and see what you get.

```
alert("lrshow is " + lrshow);
```

Then see if this makes any difference:

```
var lrshow = document.getElementById("lr_needed").value;
alert("lrshow is " + lrshow);
```